# Vercel: "Linting and checking validity of types" fails on deploy but passes locally

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma, vercel

When running locally, I can  run "next build" without problems. The command "vercel build" also works without problems. But as soon as I deploy to vercel, the "Linting and checking validity of types" fails when it's being built on vercel. Typescript is set to strict mode, but it is as if it's even stricter in when running in vercel even though it's the same codebase.

The app is based on the create-t3 app. It stops building on vercel as soon as I add a "select" statement in a prisma findUnique query. Such as in the "check-credentials" file.

In the console in vercel, it would output the following error:

```
info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
Failed to compile.
./src/pages/api/user/check-credentials.ts:33:7
Type error: Type '{ id: true; name: true; email: true; image: true; password: true; }' is not assignable to type 'UserSelect'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'password' does not exist in type 'UserSelect'.
  31 |       email: true,
  32 |       image: true,
> 33 |       password: true,
     |       ^
  34 |     },
  35 |   });
  36 |   if (user && user.password == hashPassword(req.body.password)) {
```

I have created a clone of the repository, as my best guess is that there might be a problem with ts validation and linting being ignored locally, but not on deploys:
https://github.com/Andreaswt/t3-app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like an error where your Prisma schema in CI compiles to a different output than whatever your local Prisma schema is compiling to. I'm unfamiliar with t3, but it seems that you're changing the Prisma schema without also recompiling the underlying Prisma client. You probably need to run `db-generate-client` to keep backend functionality in sync with your schema.

Comment: This was it. I added "postinstall": "prisma generate" to my package.json and redeployed in vercel, which generated the prisma client in vercel as it should. Thank you!

Comment: i use prisma js , and db generate work , thank